# Investing in US treasury bonds

Tags: united-states, bonds, government-bonds

I would like to put my money in the safe investment but I would like to earn more than regular savings account has to offer. But I would like to understand the mechanics of it for a regular investor.

In particular, I am interested in short term Treasury bills, say 3m, 6m or 12m.notes acceptable too. As I see they generate higher yield and I intend to hold them to maturity unless emergency and then I sell. Do I get coupon the same way I get dividends on stocks? Is it the same as holding dividend paying stock? Or is there an equivalent alternative out there? I want as safe as US government but consistent guaranteed return over some short period of time.

Comment: Are you talking about US treasury bonds? What country are you in?

Comment: @littleadv yes, edited, talking about US bills and notes

Comment: Mostly dupe https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/152491/how-do-i-reflect-discount-on-a-treasury-note . Note on all bonds, not just Treasuries, both interest and acquisition discount (less premium) are considered guaranteed and taxed at ordinary-income rates (except 'muni' bonds which are tax-exempt), not the preferential rates applied to some dividends and net capital gains from stock investments where you (usually) risk losing your money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they do not pay dividends. They pay interest, like a savings account or Certificate of Deposit at a bank. But like a CD, you can't withdraw that interest separately; it's just part of the value when you cash it out.

Comment: I see, bills don't. How about if I get longer maturity where they py coupons? Say 10y? But what is the interest come from? I thought it is something like I buy a bill for $97 nad then a year later I get back $100 face. Any other cash flows? So what is the difference between tbills and savings account then?

Comment: That difference between purchase price and maturity price is the interest. The difference between government bonds vs savings is similar to that between CDs vs savings -- in exchange for committing to loaning out your money for a longer time, you get a higher, guaranteed return. Plus, even if we hit another Great Depression and banks crash, as long as the government survives in something like it's current form treasury bonds will still hold their value and pay out as promised. And some folks like the patriotic aspect of lending directly to the government; certainly we saw that during WWIi.

Comment: If you want to clip coupons as you go but invest in treasuries, an index funds based in treasuries can do that. But that is no longer a guaranteed return since it responds to market forces, and may only be as safe as the brokerage running the fund. (And I should probably edit all this into my answer unless someone thinks I've got something wrong.)

Comment: I see, so the interest is the difference in amounts, makes sense. I don't have specific request on coupons. I simply want 1-2 year investment where it is save and generates income. I can see the savings account still offers lower rate compare to the US treasury. Is that just because bank gets a cut? and is there a difference between going directly buying US bonds from govt or buying some type of index fund/etf that is invested in US treasury?

Comment: I think I just answered the question about treasury-based mutual funds. Banks pay the interest they must to get people to lend them money (by depositing it into accounts) which they lend back out at a higher rate of interest and/or make other investments with.

Comment: A savings account allows access to the face value of your money instantly. Additionally, a savings account comes with services, e.g. cash withdrawal at an ATM, which costs the bank money. If you want cash from a Treasury security, you have to sell it on the secondary market, and be subject to market forces at that time. Plus, it takes a day to clear.